# nginx - How do I make server-wide configuration for every hosted website

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver

For each website I host with nginx, I have got a different file which holds the server {} block in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`

For example...
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/website1.co.uk`
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/website2.org`
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/website3.com`

I find myself repeating the same code in every server {} block and was wondering if it is possible to make a "catch all" server {} block to house the reusable code.

This new "catch all" file would include things such as...

```
# Redirect all www. attempts to non-www.
server {
  server_name www.$anything; hmm?
  return 301 $scheme://$hostname$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name _; hmm?

  # Add expires to static files
  location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)$ {
    expires max;
    access_log off;
  }

  # Pass PHP files to PHP
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

Has anyone does this before?
Do we have to repeat these types of generic codes for each website we host?

Comment: I haven't actually tested this, but I know that the nginx server_name accepts regular expressions if the value starts with a ~.  For your non-www example, say, you should be able to use `server_name "~^[^w]{3}.*$"`.  More documentation is available here:  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names

Comment: I regret to inform you of two things: regular expressions are extremely heavy on nginx, and it's usually worth having multiple PHP-FPM pools - and therefore multiple PHP `location` blocks. Generate them using a script - so much more feature-rich!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `include`. Put all boilerplate in separate files, without server blocks. `include fastcgi_params` mentioned in the sample config is a prime example.
Without a leading slash, nginx will look in the directory where the main configuration file is. So:

```
include fastcgi_params;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
```

are equivalent, if nginx.conf is in `/etc/nginx`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think I may have to use this approach. Could you explain your last sentence a little more please

Comment: He means include relative paths start at the directory containing `nginx.conf`.  So if your `nginx.conf` is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, include considers `/etc/nginx/` its PWD.